# How to restore custom layout/panels when loading a blend file with different settings?

Tags: interface

I've downloaded a .blend file recently and all of the interface elements look very small. Is there a way to quickly resize the buttons within the panels according to my personal settings?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is happening on a file you didn't create, and want to preserve your own default layout, uncheck the LoadUI box when loading the file.

[image]